# Inner Join одной рандомной строки

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Имеем две таблицы `Videos` и `Thumbs`. Отношение между объектами `video` и `thumb` - `has many`. Одно `Video` имеет 3 `Thumbs`.

Задача, одним запросом получить все видео с одной тумбой, выбранной рандомно.
Пока что мой запрос выглядит вот так:

```
SELECT v.id as video_id, t.id as thumb_id
FROM videos v
INNER JOIN thumbs t
ON t.video_id=v.id
```

Получается результат:

```
+----------+---------+
| video_id | thumb_id|
+----------+---------+
| 1        |       1 |
| 1        |       2 |
| 1        |       3 |
| 2        |       4 |
| 2        |       5 |
| 2        |       6 |
| 3        |       7 |
| 3        |       8 |
| 3        |       9 |
| 4        |      10 |
| 4        |      11 |
| 4        |      12 |
| 5        |      13 |
| 5        |      14 |
| 5        |      15 |
+----------+---------+
```

Нужен результат:

```
+----------+---------+
| video_id | thumb_id|
+----------+---------+
| 1        |       2 |
| 2        |       6 |
| 3        |       7 |
| 4        |      10 |
| 5        |      15 |
+----------+---------+
```

Comment: Использование INNER JOIN это обязательное условие? Или можно, все же, сделать LEFT JOIN?

Comment: не обязательное. я еще просто не сильно понимаю отличие inner от join. главное в данные первой таблицы добавить данные второй таблицы

Comment: Можно добавить группировку по `video_id` тогда результат будет похож на нужный вам вариант, поле `thumb_id` будет иметь не детерминированное значение. Так же можно на поле `thumb_id` засунут в агрегатную функцию, здесь я уже не подскажу, но возможно что-то есть типа рандома

Comment: Стандартный способ получения случайной записи - это `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`. Осталось уговорить эту конструкцию правильно работать в подзапросе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял входные условия, то мы имеем:

- 1ая таблица **Videos**
- 2ая таблица **Thumbs**

Отношения между ними `many-to-many`, значит есть

- 3ая таблица **Videos_Has_Thumbs**

которая содержит 2 поля - Videos_fk и Thumbs_fk. Это указатели на соответствующие поля id в таблицах Videos и Thumbs (*У вас поля могут называться по-другому, поэтому я описываю просто алгоритм работы*)

Это означает, что нужно получить записи таблицы videos и прикрепить к ним значения из таблицы thumbs.

Так как у нас 3 таблицы, - первая содержит id видео (таблица videos); вторая содержит данные о том, какое видео какие thumbs имеет (таблица videos_has_thumbs); а третья содержит id thumb'ов (таблица thumbs), то очевидно, что нам нужно два джоина:

```
SELECT
      Videos.id
    , GROUP_CONCAT(Thumbs.id)
FROM Videos
LEFT JOIN Videos_Has_Thumbs ON Videos.id = Videos_Has_Thumbs.Videos_fk
LEFT JOIN Thumbs ON Videos_Has_Thumbs.Thumbs_fk = Thumbs.id
GROUP BY Videos.id;
```

Сначала мы выбираем все видео (Select from videos).

Потом узнаем, какие у какого видео есть тумбы (join Videos_Has_Thumbs)

И наконец прикрепляем эти тумбы к нужному видео по полученным данным.

После группировки, у нас выводятся наши данные так, как мы хотим их видеть.

> Задача, одним запросом получить все видео с одной тумбой, выбранной рандомно

Если у вас имеется параметр, - в данном случае рандомный id тумбы, то запрос можно превратить в Stored Procedure и передавать туда этот параметр, подставляя id тумбы в WHERE.

Про различия между разными видами JOIN'ов можно почитать [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join).

Отношения many-to-many *всегда* строятся с использованием 3ей (junction) таблицы.

**Update после комментариев**

В случае, если отношения one-to-many (одно видео, может содержать много тумб, но одна тумба может относиться только к одному видео), Ваш запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
SELECT
      Videos.id
    , GROUP_CONCAT(Thumbs.id)
FROM Videos
LEFT JOIN Thumbs ON Videos.id = Thumbs.id
GROUP BY Videos.id;
```

Два примера выше выведут колонку со всеми thumbs, которые есть у видео.

Этот пример будет выводить id одной тумбы рандомно:

```
SELECT
      Videos.id
    , Thumbs_random.id
FROM Videos
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        Thumbs.id,
        Thumbs.Video_id
    FROM Thumbs
    ORDER BY RAND()
) AS Thumbs_random ON Videos.id = Thumbs_random.Video_id
GROUP BY Videos.id
```

Comment: третьей таблицы нет, video имеет несколько thumb, thumb принадлежит к одному video

Comment: В вашем сообщении вы описываете, что одно видео может иметь несколько thumbs, а одни и те же thumb'ы могут быть у разных видео. Например, видео с id=1 и id=5 имеет тумбу с id=2. А видео 2 и 3 имеют тумбу одинаковую тумбу 1. Это отношения many-to-many и они должны строиться через 3ю таблицу.  Если у вас эти отношения построены без третьей (junction) таблицы, то рискну сказать, что это ошибка дизайна БД. Обновлю ответ.

Comment: извиняюсь, я ввел в заблуждение. подправлю свой вопрос

Comment: @Alex ах, так там значит one-to-many отношения =) Придется мне в третий раз апдейтать ответ =)))

Comment: проверил. уже лучше, но не совсем тот результат все равно. вот такой вывод получаю
+-------+-------------------------------+
| id    | GROUP_CONCAT(thumbs.id)       |
+-------+-------------------------------+
| 69551 | 31,32,33 |
| 69552 | 41,42,43 |

т.е. выводит ид всех тумб

Comment: @Alex обновил ответ

Comment: уже лучше, выдает по одной тумбе в столбце, но выдает всё равно тумбу первую в порядке, а не рандомную

Comment: @Alex так вы запустите несколько раз запрос, - тумба будет разной.

Comment: Пробую. Всегда одна и та же, всегда первая.

Comment: @Alex не верю. Если только вы не удалили rand(). Давайте продолжим общение в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72775/chat-780960)

Comment: Подождал 20 минут, больше не могу

Comment: в чат писать не хватает репутации :(
запустил запрос тут http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8df3fa3/2 -  все работает.
у меня на сервере не работает, выдает всегда первую тумбу. буду разбираться.

Answer (score -2):

Попробуйте так

```
SELECT TOP (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(video_id) FROM videos GROUP BY 
video_id) 
v.id as video_id, t.id as thumb_id
FROM videos v
INNER JOIN thumbs t
ON t.video_id=v.id
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: А конкретнее ошибку

Comment: Поля забыл указать

Comment: @RomanIeromenko А посмотреть тег используемой СУБД не судьба?

Comment: В чем вопросы ?

Comment: Проверь пожалуйста результат запроса

Comment: @RomanIeromenko, все равно не рабтает. подозреваю что SELECT TOP не работает

Comment: Проверь все, все д.б ОК

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(video_id) FROM videos GROUP BY 
video_id)

Comment: [*Not all database systems support the SELECT TOP clause. MySQL supports the LIMIT clause to select a limited number of records*](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp). Автор вопроса спрашивает про MySQL.